# How to set form value to input name but send id?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

So I have a form input field like that:

```
<input list="materials" name="material_id" placeholder="Nazwa materiału" autocomplete="off">
    <datalist id="materials">
    @foreach($materials as $material)
    <option value="{{$material->id}}">{{$material->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
    </datalist>
```

It shows a list of materials (names) but it coresponds to material_id (foreign key) so it has to send an id value but it can be quite confusing for user. How can I set it to send id value but leave "material name" in field? (I know it is probably something from jscript or jquery but I don't know anything about them)

Comment: Your question is confusing. How you are sending Id?

Comment: Can you show us the data set for $materials?

Comment: Why aren't you using a <select> menu?

Comment: So you choose a name from list: ex. Pen but it fills input field with id value ex. 1.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `onchange` event like this

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value );
  //Do something
})
```

your html should be like this

```
<select>
    @foreach($materials as $material)
    <option value="{{$material->id}}">{{$material->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

example

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('select').on('change', function() {
                  alert( this.value );
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    //other things
    <select>
        @foreach($materials as $material)
        <option value="{{$material->id}}">{{$material->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I think you are right on how to do it. But I don't know how to handle jscript and where to put it and how to use it.

Comment: see example which is given below

Comment: you can put script body tag or head tag

Comment: i think given example is sufficient to understand

Comment: i think you want to fetch some data by choosing matrial name correspond to  $material->id

Comment: Yes. I want to fill input field with material name but send id as value

Comment: you should use ajax

Comment: Well then. Thank you for your time and advice. I will have to look into it more.

Answer (score 0):

store material id on data-value such like a

```
@foreach($materials as $material)
<option data-value="{{$material->id}}">{{$material->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```